# Applescript mail flagging not working in maverick?

Tags: email, applescript, osx-mavericks

I am working on applescript and the following does not work :

I've put the file in the script folder, created a rule which find messages but the script does never happen.

I tried to flag, change the background color to no avail. The rule "test" exists.
What is wrong here?

Code :

```
using terms from application "Mail"
-- on perform mail action with messages selectedMessages
set today to current date
set deleteDate to today - (7 * days)

on perform mail action with messages selectedMessages for rule test

    tell application "Mail"

        repeat with eachMessage in selectedMessages
            -- repeat with a from 1 to 5
            --- Process the current message
            --  set background color of eachMessage to white
            --  if date received of eachMessage in selectedMessages is after deleteDate then
            set background color of eachMessage to white
            set flagged status to false
            --  end if

            --  display dialog theText
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```